# Insertar masivamente Laravel uno a muchos

Tags: php, laravel-7

Buen día chicos tengo la siguiente duda. Al momento de guardar productos en un detalle de factura según el código que tengo implementado me doy cuenta que va a realizar varias inserciones en la base en lugar de realizarlo masivamente.

Por ejemplo en el modelo de `detalleFactura` tengo los siguientes campos.

```
detalleFactura
-transaction
-product_id
-catidad
-costo
-subtotal
```

Ahora bien al momento de guardar los datos tengo lo siguiente:

```php
$detalleFactura = new DetalleFactura();
foreach($products as $product){
   ...
   $detalleFactura->save();
}
```

Por lo tanto si tengo 100 productos voy a realizar 100 la operacion de `save`.

Cual es la alternativa para guardar todos los productos en masivo??

Comment: Si revise la documentacion pero en este caso los productos ya están creados no necesito crearlos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno encontré la forma de implementar lo que necesitaba y asi ingresar registros masivamente.

```php
        $data = [];

        foreach($products as $product){
            $detalleFactura = new DetalleFactura();
            //asignar los valores a los campos
            ...
            array_push($data, $detalleFactura);

        }

        DetalleFactura::insert($data);
```

Con esto agregamos los objetos en un array y posteriormente usamos el metodo insert.